# One concurrent service or multiple services

Tags: android, concurrency, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I'm developing an application that implements a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for incoming SMS.

For example depending on SMS received the app will:

- send a reply with SIM info
- send a reply with IMEI info
- send a reply with current GPS position
- etc

How should this be implemented?

I thought of two ways of doing it, first with one service for each functionality but I feel it's overkill. On the other hand I though of creating one service that behaves like a controller and creates one thread for each request.

It needs to be concurrent because some actions can take 1 second and another can take 1 or 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a single service that is concurrent.  You can use a thread-pool and submit jobs to it as they arrive.  Then you won't have to worry about a long running job affecting your entire service.

This does mean, however, that you will have to worry about concurrent accesses to the various different services.  If each service will only be processing a single transaction at once then it may be easier to create a service for each type of request.

If you decide on a concurrent service, then following code is an example of how you could use an `ExecutorService` thread-pool.

```
// create a thread pool with a dynamic number of workers
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
while (!shutdown) {
    // read your SMS job into an object
    SmsMessage message = receiveSmsMessage();
    threadPool.submit(new SmsJob(message));
}
// once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown
threadPool.shutdown();
...
public class SmsJob implements Runnable {
    private SmsMessage message;
    public MyJobProcessor(SmsMessage message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public void run() {
        // process the message
    }
}
```

Comment: At the moment 1 service = 1 transaction, so I will stick to one service for each request. But it's nice to know how to do it concurrently.